# Inserting a value on a frozen set in cassandra 3

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

I am currently working on a Cassandra 3 database in which one of its tables has a column that is defined like this:

```
column_name map<int, frozen <set<int>>>
```

When I have to change the value of a complete set given a map key **x** I just have to do this:

```
UPDATE keyspace.table SET column_name[x] = {1,2,3,4,5} WHERE ...
```

The thing is that I need to insert a value on a set given a key. I tried with this:

```
UPDATE keyspace.table SET column_name[x] = column_name[x] + {1} WHERE ...
```

But it returns:

> SyntaxException: line 1:41 no viable alternative at input '[' (... SET column_name[x] = [column_name][...)

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone know how to insert data the way I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since the value of map is frozen, you can't use update like this.**

> A frozen value serializes multiple components into a single value. Non-frozen types allow updates to individual fields. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen type as a blob. The entire value must be overwritten.

*You have to read the full map get the value of the key append new item and then reinsert*

Comment: is there a way to do this through cql?

Comment: @VenelinK I am not sure but you can try to create user define function https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html